# Is it obligatory for every Muslim to believe that a person, who is a confirmed to be a kafir, is a kafir?

Tags: kufr

Is it obligatory for every Muslim to believe that a person, who is confirmed to be a kafir, is a kafir?

I don't know if my neighbours are kafir or not.  But we are of a different race and most of the people of my neighbour's race are kafirs. Some of my neighbours also own dogs. If I don't regard them as disbelievers, does that make me a disbeliever? Jazakallah khayran.

Answer (score 1):

Recognition of Kuffar being obligatory is not about things you do not know.

It is not about being obligatory to investigate to find out if someone is a believer or not.

Rather, it is about things you do know. If you know something about a person for sure that is clear disbelief but still believe he is not a disbeliever, that is what it is about.

Meaning: If you know that someone is a Christian, you cannot doubt his kufr then. Because it is known for sure that Christians are confirmed kuffar.

If you don't know anything about a person that makes it clear to you his beliefs, why would anything be obligatory on you?

Use a bit of logic as well. How can it be obligatory for someone to know something they do not know? If you see someone random in a crowd, how are you supposed to determine if they're Muslim?

Comment: Jazakallah khayran bro.May Allah reward you.Im also think about what you saying but Im afraid that i have became disbelieve.thanks bro.jazakallah khayran

Comment: @Mikhaeil You are not a disbeliever. There is no such thing as accidental disbelief. Those are waswasah, ignore them